# How get get traceback on the console

Tags: django

I have this in a django view:

```
import logging

from django.conf import settings

fmt = getattr(settings, 'LOG_FORMAT', None)
lvl = getattr(settings, 'LOG_LEVEL', logging.INFO)

logging.basicConfig(format=fmt, level=lvl)

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def index(request):
    if request.GET.get("request_id"):
        logging.info("standard CMH request...")
        barf()
     # etc
```

In my work environment (DEBUG=True) this prints on the console when I access the relevant page over REST from a client app:

```
mgregory$ foreman start
19:59:11 web.1  | started with pid 37371
19:59:11 web.1  | 2014-10-10 19:59:11 [37371] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
19:59:11 web.1  | 2014-10-10 19:59:11 [37371] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (37371)
19:59:11 web.1  | 2014-10-10 19:59:11 [37371] [INFO] Using worker: sync
19:59:11 web.1  | 2014-10-10 19:59:11 [37374] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 37374
19:59:18 web.1  | standard CMH request...
```

What is actually happening is that `barf()` is throwing an exception, because it's not defined.   But this isn't appearing in the console log.

How can I get all exceptions to appear in the console log, in DEBUG=True environment?

---

Supplementary: is there any reason why I wouldn't have this do the same in the production environment, with DEBUG=False?   My production environment does not email me, I'd love to have these exceptions in the log, I think?

Comment: try _foreman run python app.py_ instead of _foreman start_

Comment: Thanks, but no joy.   Note (and I will update the question too): I'm accessing this server via REST calls from an application, not from a browser.   With DEBUG=True, acecssing from the browser gets a traceback presented from Django in the browser window.   However, the app just gets a 500 error.   It's in this condition that I need the console to get the traceback.